# Strange alignment and layout in tableviewer with image

Tags: image, alignment, swt, jface, tableviewer

I use a `TableViewer` with two columns. The first should contain text and the second an image depending on the state of the object. The label provider is a custom provider which extends `LabelProvider` and implements `ITableLayoutProvider`.

When no image is displayed, the layout is correct and the text in the first column is aligned to the left.
[image: correct]

But when at least one image is displayed the text in the first column is aligned somewhere between right and center - looks kind of ugly.

[image: incorrect]

The layout is quite simple:

```
availableDevicesList = new TableViewer(this, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER
| SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
availableDevicesList.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

Table table = availableDevicesList.getTable();
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout();
table.setLayout(tableLayout);

table.setLinesVisible(true);

tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(3));
new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(1));
new TableColumn(table, SWT.RIGHT);
```

What causes this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Windows API [see SWT bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=43910). It affects only first column in table, so official workaround is to "skip" first column and set it to zero size (see last comment on bug report), but on Mac OS X table column cannot have zero size, so there will be visible first column with size 1 or something like this..

Yeah, hate this bug in Win API too..